# POST ajax request to API and display response with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, post

I'm trying to submit a form request to a RESTFUL API with ajax, and display the response in a div below the form. I have the following, but going blank on what I'm missing. The user should enter an integer value, and receive a JSON response similar to the following:

```
{
"status": {
    "code": 200,
    "description": "OK"
},
"entity": "sN0u7"
```

}

I need to display the `"entity"` value, along with a static URL prepended to the result. Example: `http://www.url.com/sN0u7`

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" id="encodeID" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by ID">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="share-link well"></div>`
```

**jQuery**

```
var name = $("#encodeID").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://url.com/rest/v1/utils/guid/encode/' + 'encodeID',
    data: dataString,
    success: function (data) {
        $(".share-link").val(data);
    });
}
});
return false;
```

**Current Fiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/6ywbtsys/)**

Comment: What event are you using to kick off the ajax request? From your fiddle, it doesn't look like any - it looks like you're trying to run the ajax call before anything else has happened.

Comment: @kinakuta, when the user clicks the "Go" button.

Comment: your setting `var name = $("#encodeID").val();` but using `+ 'encodeID'` at the end of your url.  are you setting `encodeID` elsewhere in your code? otherwise it should be `+ name`

Comment: @M.Doye, that was corrected later on to url: `https://www.url.com/rest/v1/utils/guid/encode/' + name`. Not an issue.

Comment: aha, I see... in that case, the next thing i would do is change `$(".share-link").val(data);`  to `$(".share-link").html(data);` in your success callback

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ajax call to execute when someone clicks the "Go" button, you need to attach a click handler to the button that then calls the ajax code (and since you want to attach a handler to a DOM element, I suggest putting your code in jQuery's DOM ready callback to make sure the element can be selected before attaching a handler):

```
$(function () {
  $('button.btn-default').click(function () {
    var name = $('#encodeID').val();
    $ajax(...);
  });
});
```

Right now your code will try to execute before the user has done anything. Also, you may consider putting the input inside a form element, and using the POST url as the action for the form element. That part isn't necessary for making an ajax call, but then your page could theoretically work without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of syntax errors and the click event is not handled. Try the below code with actual url and try it once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button.btn-default').click(function(){
    var dataString = $("#encodeID").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://url.com/rest/v1/utils/guid/encode/' + dataString ,
        data: dataString,
        success: function (data) {
            $(".share-link").html(data);
        }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is working, but because of CORS, I can't get a response currently. I'm trying to get the error code for a bad response in place(and place an error message in the `share-link` div, but having an issue. Thoughts?

Comment: oh yeah change that val method to text or html. I have updated the above as well.

     $(".share-link").html(data);